# Extract and rename zip file from specific folder using Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python3.10. To unzip a file I have a zip file in folder 'wowo' if I select folder using path and use only file name the code doesn't work. But, when full path+filename given it works. I don't want go give full path and file name together. I want to define path saperately.

```
zipdata = zipfile.ZipFile('/Volumes/MacHD/MYPY/wowo/NST_cm.zip')
    zipinfos = zipdata.infolist()
    for zipinfo in zipinfos:
    zipinfo.filename = 'Nst.csv'
    zipdata.extract(path=path, member=zipinfo)
```

Comment: what i need is
path = '/Volumes/macHD/MYPY/wowo'
zipdata = zipfile.ZipFile(path,'NST_cm.zip')

Comment: `zipdata = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(path,'NST_cm.zip'))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pathlib and add the path with the filename in the zipfile.zipfile:

```
import pathlib
path = pathlib.Path('PATH/TO/FOLDER')

zipfile.ZipFile( path / 'filename')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could join the two strings in order to form the full filepath.

```
filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
zipfile.ZipFile(filepath)
```

Or I believe the ZipFile function can take a path and file name expression like this

```
zipfile.ZipFile(path,'filename')
```

Replacing filename with the name of the file you wish to work with